# MySQL giving duplicate Entry error when trying to increment date field?

Tags: mysql, duplicates, increment

I am reading in data from an XML file. Due to an error at the source it is one day out, so after loading into the database I use this SQL statement to increment the date.

```
UPDATE 2011_electricity SET DATE = DATE_ADD( DATE, INTERVAL 1 DAY )
```

Last week it worked fine, however now I get an error:

```
MySQL said: 

#1062 - Duplicate entry '2011-07-20' for key 1
```

I have one primary key on the data field. This is how the database looks:

```
                date        energy  daynum
        2011-06-29  0.05    4197
        2011-07-19  0.20    4219
        2011-07-20  17.07   4220
        2011-07-21  11.56   4221
        2011-07-22  18.18   4222
        2011-07-23  24.92   4223
        2011-07-24  10.56   4224
        2011-07-25  12.68   4225
        2011-07-26  10.06   4226
        2011-07-27  19.72   4227
        2011-07-28  19.02   4228
        2011-07-29  17.92   4229
        2011-07-30  14.49   4230
        2011-07-31  10.84   4231
        2011-08-01  13.38   4232
        2011-08-02  14.86   4233
```

I cannot see any duplicate there, so do not understand the error, is there a better way to carry out mysql code to increment the day by 1?

Answer (score 2):

This is a problem on how MySQL's `UPDATE` works, row by row as p.cambell explained. Another way to bypass this issue, is to explicitely tell the engine how to order the updates (another MySQL quirk):

```
UPDATE 2011_electricity 
SET DATE = DATE_ADD( DATE, INTERVAL 1 DAY )
ORDER BY DATE DESC
```

Rule of thumb: If you want to increase the PKs (or other Unique Key), order by descending. If you want to decrease the PKs, order by ascending.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to update the PK values on the table. Aside: suggest finding another PK for this table. Here's what's happening.

Row by row:

- update the PK for `2011-06-29` to be `2011-06-30`. This **succeeds** as there's no other row with that PK value.
- update the PK for `2011-07-19` to be `2011-07-20`. This **fails** as there's already another row with that PK value. The pre-existing row's PK hasn't been incremented yet. We've now violated the PK constraint.

Suggest modifying your approach to either:

- Delete all your new data in the table, and reload from source as you're doing now.
- leverage a staging/temp table if deleting isn't an option. You might want to swap out rows selectively as per your needs.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense, but it worked last week with a weeks worth of data! I guess a staging table is the way forward, I don't suppose I can do anything as simple as telling the UPDATE to write the result into a new table?