# Can I increment a date field as part of a MySQL Update?

Tags: php, mysql, date

I have this SQL statement below

```
INSERT into 2011_electricity ( date, energy, daynum) VALUES (STR_TO_DATE('$date','%d%m%y'),'$energy','$num'
```

Is it possible to increment the date by one day AS I insert it into the database?

Or could I increment it in PHP before inserting it?

The string format in PHP prior to the MySQL statement is as follows:

> 190711

Which is 19th July 2011.

thanks,

Greg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [DATE_ADD()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add) function. So your statement would became

```
...VALUES (DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE('$date','%d%m%y'), INTERVAL 1 DAY), ...
```

Comment: I don't think his date is in a date column. Rather in a `VARCAHR`.

Comment: @Emil Wouldn't this work anyway? DATE_ADD(STR_TO_DATE('$date', '%d%m%y'), INTERVAL 1 DAY)

Comment: I tried date_add after loading the data, but that causes me problems incrementing into a date that already exists, see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6968247/mysql-giving-duplicate-entry-error-when-trying-to-increment-date-field

Comment: @JK: It might, but that is not what ain has answered. :)

Comment: @Emil it must be date column as he uses `STR_TO_DATE` function which converts a string to a date.

Answer (score 1):

Once you use STR_TO_DATE, you have a valid date, you can do this :

```
STR_TO_DATE('$date', '%d%m%y') + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```